# isset($_POST[""]) working but not much as i've expected

Tags: php, forms, str-replace

I've made a "simple" page maker that merge forms with placeholders and used PHP to replace the info and submit the page into the website, but it is working for Name,Type and Description, but the others aren't working, and i've made them in the same way. (see: http://www.swordsdb.url.ph/)
The codes that i've used are:

**addpage.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Página Administrativa</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="process.php" method="post" id="dados">
            Título:<input type="text" name="title" /><br />
            Nome:<input type="text" name="name" /><br />
            Imagem: "Em Construção" <br />
            Tipo:
            <select name="type">
                <option value="1">Item normal</option>
                <option value="2">Item usável</option>
                <option value="3">Item de Quest</option>
                <option value="4">Material</option>
                <option value="5">Gift/Presente</option>
            </select><br />
            Buy/Sell:<input type="text" name-"buysell" /><br />
            Descrição:<textarea name="description" form="dados" cols="40" rows="2"></textarea><br />
            Dropmonster(1):<input type="text" name-"drmon1" /><br />
            Dropmonster(2):<input type="text" name-"drmon2" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/><br />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
$null = "Nenhum(a)";
if (isset($_POST["title"])) {
    $data["title"] = $_POST["title"];
} //*Fim da titulação
if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
    $data["name"] = $_POST["name"];
} //*Fim da nomeação
if (isset($_POST["image"])) {
    $data["image"] = $_POST["image"];
} else {
    $data["image"] = $null;
} //*Fim da Imagem
if (isset($_POST["type"])) {
    $data["type"] = $_POST["type"];
    if ($data["type"] == 1) {
        $data["type"] = "Item normal";
        $members_path = "pages/normal/"; //*Diretório dos Itens Normais
    } elseif ($data["type"] == 2) {
        $data["type"] = "Item usável";
        $members_path = "pages/usable/"; //*Diretório dos Itens Usáveis
    } elseif ($data["type"] == 3) {
        $data["type"] = "Item de Quest";
        $members_path = "pages/quest/"; //*Diretório dos Itens de Quest
    } elseif ($data["type"] == 4) {
        $data["type"] = "Material";
        $members_path = "pages/material/"; //*Diretório dos Materiais
    } elseif ($data["type"] == 5) {
        $data["type"] = "Gift/Presente";
        $members_path = "pages/gift/"; //*Diretório dos Gifts
    }
} //*Fim da Nomeação do Type
if (isset($_POST["buysell"])) {
    $data["buysell"] = $_POST["buysell"];
} else {
    $data["buysell"] = $null;
} //*Fim da inserção de valores

if (isset($_POST["description"])) {
    $data["description"] = $_POST["description"];
} else {
    $data["description"] = $null;
} //*Fim da descrição
if (isset($_POST["drmon1"])) {
    $data["drmon1"] = $_POST["drmon1"];
    echo $data["drmon1"];
} else {
    $data["drmon1"] = $null;
} //*Fim do DropMob1
if (isset($_POST["drmon2"])) {
    $data["drmon2"] = $_POST["drmon2"];
    echo $data["drmon2"];
} else {
    $data["drmon2"] = $null;
} //*Fim do DropMob2

$placeholders = array(
    "{title}",
    "{name}",
    "{image}",
    "{type}",
    "{buysell}",
    "{description}",
    "{drmon1}",
    "{drmon2}"
);
$tpl_file     = "placeholder.php"; //*Página de Template
$tpl_path     = ""; //*Diretório do Template
$tpl          = file_get_contents($tpl_path . $tpl_file);
sleep(1);
$new = str_replace($placeholders, $data, $tpl);
sleep(1);
$html_file_name = $data['name'] . ".html";
$fp             = fopen($members_path . $html_file_name, "w");
fwrite($fp, $new);
fclose($fp);
header('Location: ' . $members_path . $data["name"] . '.html');
?>
```

You can see it kinda working at: [http://www.http://swordsdb.url.ph/](http://swordsdb.url.ph/)

What am i missing here?

Comment: whr is ur ths check if(isset($_POST['submit']){ and idk but thr should be a name <input type='submit' name='submit' value='' />  thn it will do the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I noticed in your file was a - sign instead of a = sign in the form. This might be why the post data isn't coming through

```
Buy/Sell: <input type="text" name-"buysell" /><br />
Dropmonster(1): <input type="text" name-"drmon1" /><br />
Dropmonster(2): <input type="text" name-"drmon2" /><br />
```

try changing it to

```
Buy/Sell: <input type="text" name="buysell" /><br />
Dropmonster(1): <input type="text" name="drmon1" /><br />
Dropmonster(2): <input type="text" name="drmon2" /><br />
```

I haven't pulled this into a working area but that is where i would start most of your post information in the php file looks fine.